# telerik radtreeview and virtualization property

Tags: silverlight, telerik, radtreeview

I have used the telerik radtreeview and virtualization property to IsVirtualizing = true . I have achieved the optimization but my treeview items not completely loded (Half filled and half empty treeview) when I scroll down then the items moved up and empty part still exist. please help.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need these properties in your TreeView Decaration:

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" 
ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
```

Comment: i did not use the VirtualizingStackPanel. istead of this i used Telerik.Windows.Controls.TreeView.TreeViewPanel.SetIsVirtualizing(this.TreeDest,true);

Comment: Anyway,if you SetIsVirtualizing you're creating VirtualizingStackPanel.

Comment: but its not working for me how i can show all the items ?? please help.